# Check which libraries are needed

Tags: android, c++, makefile, gstreamer, ld

**How can I check which libraries I need to link with my Android application?** I mean that I get many of errors like `error: undefined reference to 'function_name'` and I need to resolve them manually - look for some matches in the libraries names and add them to the my project. But it's not always works, for example now I try to use Gstreamer on Android and get some unresolved dependencies, I don't know in which library these functions are located:

- undefined reference to 'g_simple_proxy_resolver_new'
- undefined reference to 'gst_preset_get_type'

**So, how and where can I find libraries which contains these functions?**

Comment: You google the variable type and you should be able to find what to import by look at sample codes of that type

Comment: @FirstStep if you talk about functions names, then I already tried to google them, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: The `grep` function is your friend.  Search the compiler directory for header files that contain the symbols; and also try searching the source files for the symbols.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ok, thanks, I already use grep too. For example I found some header or source, which contains this function, but I can't find library with the same name as header. What I need to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way is to use readelf with grep maybe with help of find..

```
find . -type f -name "*.so" | while read file; do echo $file; readelf -Ws $file | grep gst_preset_get_type; done
```

Output:

```
./ext/alsa/.libs/libgstalsa.so ./ext/theora/.libs/libgsttheora.so    
./ext/cdparanoia/.libs/libgstcdparanoia.so ./ext/libvisual/.libs
/libgstlibvisual.so ./ext/ogg/.libs/libgstogg.so
49: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_preset_get_type
518: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_preset_get_type 
...
./gst/encoding/.libs/libgstencodebin.so
37: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_preset_get_type
232: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_preset_get_type
```

You can search in /usr/lib or so..

Maybe you are also missing some plugins? try to set variable GST_PLUGINS_PATH which should point to directory containing gstreamer plugins (which are loaded at runtime)

Comment: I had invalid sequence of linker flags, the problem was in this. After this I always used your command for finding functions. Thanks, very useful!